# IIS do not see WCF service

Tags: wcf, iis, config, endpoint

I have AjaxDataService.svc placed in my root directory.
Since the root folder has its content deployed automatically i se no reason why there should be anything missing.
Only thing that comes to mind is having a bad .config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="WashMyCarHomepage.AjaxEntityService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WashMyCarHomepage.IAjaxEntityService" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://sub.project.com" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

It runs smoothly on localhost. Also the rest of the application runs as expected.

**edit:**
Could someone list possible reasons?

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you browse the service?

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: What is the IIS version you are using? Try enabling Web service extensions node

Comment: I am running on IIS 8, Windows server 2012. I fallowed this tutorial  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/08/17/iis7-where-is-the-web-services-extensions-option-which-was-there-in-iis6.aspx since there is no "Web service extensions node" feature in IIS 8. All existing items are set to "Allowed", I also did enable "unspecified CGI modules" and "unspecified ISAPI modules" but it didn't help. Therefore i disable it again.